# How to disable boot screen in Windows 7 via registry?

Tags: windows-7, registry

I can't find registry, which will disable boot screen in Windows 7.
Anyone got this? It looks like this:

http://www.sevenforums.com/attachments/tutorials/227743d1379314006t-gui-boot-enable-disable-windows-windows-7.jpg

Answer (score 0):

you will need more than just a registry key or something like that. Have a look at this tutorial:

http://www.askvg.com/change-windows-7-boot-screen-using-windows-7-boot-updater/

There is also a free tool linked which can be used to create customized boot screens on Windows 7. You will be able to modify the image, insert a custom animation or the texts.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen similar tutorials, but I was wondering that I can do it by registry key